# Instantiate all classes implementing a specific interface

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an interface `IExample`, and a set of classes `ClassOne`, `ClassTwo` and `ClassThree`, all defined in different namespaces. I will possibly remove either of the classes, or add a new one in a new place, at a later stage in development.

Now, I want to **find all types that implement `IExample` at runtime, and instantiate them**. (I know on beforehand that no class implementing `IExample` will ever need any constructor arguments, but I don't know how to specify that in code, so it's me - not the compiler - that knows...)

Is this possible? How do I go about to do it?

**Update:** I've now tried several of the approaches suggested, but on all of them, the line `Activator.CreateInstance(type)`, I get a System.MissingMethodException because I "cannot create an instance of an interface." This is my code:

```
var tasks = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => typeof(IBootstrapperTask).IsAssignableFrom(t))

    // This line is where it fails
    .Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IBootstrapperTask)

    .ToArray();
new AutoMapperBootstrapper(tasks).Initialize();
```

Without the `as` clause I don't see any exception, but I'm given an `object[]`, and I need an `IBootstrapperTask[]` for the constructor on the last line in the excerpt. I've tried various ways to cast it, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can be done with Reflection.  For example

```
var interfaceType = typeof(IExample);
var all = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
  .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
  .Where(x => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
  .Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x));
```

Note: This will only create instances of `IExample` from assemblies loaded in the current `AppDomain`.  This can be different than all assemblies loaded in the current process.  However for many types of applications this will be equivalent.

Comment: More importantly though, it will only include assemblies which have already been *loaded*. There may be others which have been *referenced* but not loaded yet. Personally I prefer to keep it all explicit :)

Answer (score 8):

You'd need to know a list of assemblies to look in, but then LINQ makes it relatively easy:

```
var instances = (from assembly in assemblies
                 from type in assembly
                 where !type.IsAbstract && 
                       type.IsClass &&
                       type.IsPublic &&
                       !type.IsGenericType &&
                       typeof(IExample).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                 let ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
                 where ctor != null && ctor.IsPublic
                 select (IExample) Activator.CreateInstance(type))
                .ToList();
```

You may think of some other restrictions to add, but they're pretty easy to express :)

`instances` will then be a `List<IExample>`.

EDIT: I suspect *my* code will work where yours didn't, because I'm specifically excluding non-classes. My guess is that your code is trying to instantiate the interface itself, i.e. when `t` is `typeof(IBootstrapperTask)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - please see my update for further info.

Comment: @Tomas: Edited. Did you try my solution? (Change the last line to `ToArray` if you want.) Admittedly I can't see why the `as` would have made any difference to your original code...

Comment: Thanks. When I looked closer at your code I noticed the explicit requirements of being public, non-abstract and with a constructor, and implemented them in my code as well. Now this specific part works, but I have other (possibly non-related) problems, so I'm unable to see if this actually works, or just throws a different exception.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need this to happen dynamically?  Are there ever times when you might have one that you don't want to create?  Seems to me that this is a good case for dependency injection (which can be configured).  For example Unity has a [ResolveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainer.resolveall.aspx) method .

From the above link;

```
IEnumerable<IMyObject> objects = myContainer.ResolveAll<IMyObject>();
```

Comment: With only the limited example information I gave in my question this is a valid argument, but in this case DI is not applicable.

Comment: Ha - just because I was so quick to dismiss DI, it turns out this is where I'll end up anyway... :P Thanks! However, I won't mark this as the answer, simply because it doesn't really answer the question ("how do I find all classes that implement this interface dynamically?"), even though it solves my actual problem.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! I had been building a project using Caliburn.Micro to handle all of my MVVM related things and it never came to me that I could use it to solve this problem as well! Anyone else who likes this solution should give this framework a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflection to get the types implementing `IExample`. This example looks at the current assembly but you could easily pass a different assembly:

```
        IEnumerable<Type> types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes().Where(t=>t.GetInterfaces().Where(tt==typeof(IExample)).Count()>0);
        List<object> objects = new List<object>();
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            objects.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `Contains`?  Also, that won't handle inheritance.

Comment: This will fail, since I can't create instances of interfaces - I must create instances of the types that implement them.

Comment: This will not fail! I am calling `t.GetInterfaces()` on the types. I am using something similar in a project of mine.